# Protractor: get element on the basis of innerhtml

Tags: javascript, protractor

I do e2e-tests with Protractor.

There I need to get an element on the basis of the innerhtml content. But I don't know how to do this.

In the html code it looks like that:

```
<div class="scroll" style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);">

<label class="item item-radio" ng-repeat="locale in locales">
     <input type="radio" name="group" ng-checked="false" ng-click="updateLocale(locale)">
     <div class="item-content ng-binding">
        English (USA)
     </div>
     <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
</label>
```

Now I need the element "**input**" on the basis of the innerhtml of "**English (USA)**.

What I have tested is that here:

```
var languageOption = element(by.className('input div item-content ng-binding').getText()).toBe('English (USA)');
```

I always get the error "**has no method 'getText'**"
What I do wrong?

Comment: No ideas how to get an element on the basis of the innerhtml content?

Comment: Your div is not a child of the input, it's a sibling. Since it is after the input there is no way to select it with css. Your HTML code seems wrong. Why would you have a repeater that lists only English (USA) for each option? Also the test should look like: expect(element(by.css('selector')).getText()).toBe('blah blah'); getText is a method for the element, not the selector. And you need an expectation to compare it with a toBe method.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard, so you have to create unique ids for every input element (or another elements) in ng-repeat.

I did this so:

```
<input id="locale{{$index}}"...>
```

You can define the first one as you want. With the solution from above I get this:

locale0
locale1
locale2
... and so on

Then you can get the element like this:

```
element(by.id('locale0'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use map and then filter. Use map to return then text of the div and the input, then filter the result of the map based on the div text.

```js
it('should ...', function() {
  var localeToLookFor = 'English (USA)';

  // Use map to return the text and the input.
  $$('.item.item-radio').map(function(row) {
    return {
      text: row.$('item-content').getText(),
      input: row.$('input');
    }
  }).then(function(rows) {
    // Here you have an array with elements.
    // Array.<{text: string, input: WebElement}>
    // Find the text you are looking for and return.
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      if (rows[i].text === localeToLookFor) {
        return rows[i];
      }
    }
    throw Error('Could not find element');
  }).then(function(radioInput) {
    // Here you should have a WebElement with the radio.
  });
});
```